# Present perfect or past perfect with Already

Tags: present-perfect, past-perfect

Look at the sentence :

• When we got to the theater, the play (already start)

how should I write it properly?

• When we got to the theater, the play already has started.
Or
•When we got to the theater, the play had already started.

Comment: They are both grammatical—although the first is uncommon and a little odd. Normally, it would be ***has already*** instead of *already has*. Which leads me to ask, why are you modifying **two** things at once? If you're concerned only with the verb tense, change only that single variable. Don't change the word order at the same time. Comparing *already* ***has*** with ***had*** *already* unnecessarily complicates the question.